# Cloud messaging with cloud function

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-messaging

How many usage rate when i send notification to multiple iOS devices on firebase cloud function?

I want to send to many users by the fcm token and name.

For example..
Title: Hello (Name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*firebaser here*

If you're wondering whether Firebase Cloud Messaging can deliver the volume of messages that you apps needs, the answer is probably yes.

Keep in mind that FCM is the only reliable mechanism to deliver messages to an app on Android that isn't actively being used, so any app on your phone that needs this functionality uses FCM for it. The needs of your app likely are minor in comparison to many of them, but are definitely just a blip when you compare it to the sum of all of them.

Comment: So no there limit for iOS?